# What method is called when UINavigationController is presented?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to subclass the `UINavigationController` to add a custom subview underneath its `UINavigationBar`. The problem is when I set my custom `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` of my `window`, the `UINavigationBar` position changes, so I want to update the position of my custom view accordingly. My question is where should I put my code to update my custom view.

```
    var navController = TabbedNavigationController(rootViewController: firstView)

    // navController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = 0
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    // navController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = 20.0
```

Comment: Have you seen Apple's [Customizing UINavigationbar sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)?  They have a specific example showing how to extend the navigation bar to fit a control.

Comment: @PetahChristian Yes and no. In fact they do _not_ extend the navigation bar; they just position another view below it. And this would not at all work in a UINavigationController; Apple cheats by using a _presented_ view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is respond to the positioning of subviews of the navigation controller's view. Positioning of subviews is called *layout*, and takes place in `layoutSubviews`. Thus, you could try implementing `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called immediately after `layoutSubviews`. Note that it can be called many times but you may want to add your subview only once, so be careful to add appropriate guards.

Comment: Thanks! found the layoutSubview method but did not know how it was linked to the controller!

Comment: I have position my custom view successfully but got another problem which is my viewController's view would be hidden underneath my custom view controller. Do you know how I could fix this? Thanks

Comment: @doog do you understand how views are layered back to front?

Comment: Kind of, are you suggesting I should put my subview on the same layer viewController's view and the navigationBar?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you are in charge of where views go.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the "view" of the ViewController to extend underneath the UINavigationBar. Here's some code to help you out, it's not Swift, it's ObjC but you will get the point. This is from my custom implementation of UIVeiwController subclass. I also have a full implementation of UINavigationController and UINavigationBar to adjust the size in points of the UINavigationBar. I can tell you that you can do what Apple has done in their example by just following the code I'm linking here.

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTranslucent:TRUE];
[[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] layer] setShadowOpacity:0.0f];
[[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
```